# response.sendredirect() change method type

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, jakarta-ee

In my servlet i'm trying to response.sendRedirect() a request to another servlet (which is deployed via different .war). I understood that sendRedirect() makes a new request while forwarding, but looks like there is no mechanism to change new request's method type. Basically i'm trying to see if there is an option to choose Get or Post while calling sendRedirect.

Please suggest me if there is a way to change the request type or if not i'm trying to understand why it is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`response.sendRedirect`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) is always a `GET` [also in broad term , redirect always GET s]. You can forward for your choice

**See Also**

- [java-servlet-difference-between-send-redirect-and-forward-in-servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591918/java-servlet-difference-between-send-redirect-and-forward-in-servlets)
- [URL Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)

Answer (score 2):

`response.sendRedirect` will always be a get as Jigar mentioned.
You can post to the target by having a hidden form with method post and submitting it with javascript when the page is loaded.